# When a method is synchronized, can we use StringBuilder over StringBuffer?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have a method which is synchronized. I want to use a string buffer to form a long concatenated string. I know both StringBuffer and StringBuilder can do this job. At the same time, I think StringBuilder is better since it will not incur any additional synchronization costs as the method already does that.

What do you say?

Comment: Post the method; I suspect it would be okay even without synchronization.

Comment: If your `StringBuilder` is a local variable of the method, it would be OK even if the method itself is not synchronized.

Comment: Yes, I agree that a local variable is safe from concurrency issues unless something really subtle happens which cannot be predicted upfront.

Comment: StringBuilder is also better as you have explicit synchronization.  It is very easy to misuse StringBuffer on the assumption that you don't have to worry about thread safety if you do. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/why-synchronized-stringbuffer-was-never.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as multiple threads aren't accessing the `StringBuilder` itself or causing it to be accessed in a concurrent manner, then you should be fine.

In your case, if the method the `StringBuilder/Buffer` is in is `synchronized`, only one thread should have access to it at any one time, so a `StringBuilder` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you are managing thread safety from your side then `StringBuilder` is good option and in latter case `StringBuffer` would be better.

Managing thread safety from yourself is always better because sometimes you have very small **critical section** in your code so there `method level Synchronization` is not necessary only `block level` is enough but in methods like `StringBuffer` sometimes synchronization causes a high cost but anyway it's up to your need.

Answer (score 0):

As your object of StringBuilder is not shared with other threads , you can use that..